# Pointcut for methods with at least one annotation with any type

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am trying to have the following logic;

- Method within class `x.b.Classy`
- Public method
- It has at least one annotation of any type

I have been trying to use this but annotation with any type logic is failing, how do I represent class type with 100% wildcard?

```
@Pointcut("within(x.b.Classy) && execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(*)")
```

Though getting the following;

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'identifier'
within(x.b.Classy) && execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(*)
                                                               ^
```

How do I represent **any type of annotation** within my pointcut definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want is something like:

```
@Pointcut("within(x.b.Classy) && execution(@(*) public * *(..))")
```